# How Can I Stream Video from SD Card over Ethernet via RTSP?

Tags: streaming, ffmpeg, vlc, rtsp, h264

Problem:

I need to stream a video file from my RPi SD card over RTSP to display on a client computer. I'm new to RPi and Linux-based interfaces. I'm also new to RTSP and video streaming.

My hardware:

- Raspberry Pi 3B running Debian, updated to latest version
- Computer
- Ethernet cable

Progress so far:

- Installed vlc on computer and RPi. I thought this would be a fairly simple operation to perform with just vlc on both ends, but it has
- Set RPi to static IP. I'm SSH'ing from my computer.
- Installed ffmpeg on RPi for potential streaming solution. Used it to strip an .avi to .h264 in hopes that would help.

At this point I'm running the command:

```
    cvlc -vvv "Humvee_Large.h264" --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}'
```

It seems to run without errors, but when I attempt to connect to a Network Stream in VLC player on the computer (verified I have the correct IP and port), it gives the error:

> "Your input can't be opened:
>   VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://192.168.20.31:8554/'. Check the log for details."

Answer (score 1):

Try using this command

```
vlc "Humvee_Large.h264":sout=#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/} :sout-keep
```

If you can access GUI, try using VLC's GUI streaming setup.